# Evaluate triple integral without using integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Evaluate the integral
>   $$\int_{-2}^2\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}(z^3\cos xyz-3)\,dz\,dy\,dx$$
>   without using integration. A brief explanation of how you derived your answer is required.

To start can you write it as
$$2\iiint(z^3\cos xyz-3)\,dz\,dy\,dx$$
with the limits being the same at the top and $0$ at the bottom? What is the next step?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

- $f\left(z\right)=z^3 \cos\left(xyz\right)$ is an odd function.
- $$\iiint_{\rm D} \, {\rm d}x \, {\rm d}y \, {\rm d}z = \operatorname{Vol}\left({\rm D}\right)$$ Can you identify the shape of your integration domain?

Comment: is the shape of the domain a sphere? also if its an odd function, then can you not do what I thought you can write it as?

Comment: @kenny The shape of the domain is indeed a ball (the volume bounded by a sphere). Also, you are right you can't replace the integral by $2$ times integral over the domain contained in the first octant.

Answer (score 0):

If you integrate an odd function over a region symmetric about the origin you get $0,$ and if you integrate a constant function over that region you get the product of that constant and the volume.

Comment: so would the integral be 4$\pi r^3 $ because the volume element is 4$\pi r^3 $/3 and the constant is 3?

Comment: @kenny . Yes. And note that $r=2.\qquad$